# Copying the classes and web pages and classes to new project throws error

Tags: vb.net

I'm creating a web application using VB.net . I have just copied all the classes and  web pages into new project from an old project . Everything in the code behind file doesn't recognize or couldn't the elements in the default.aspx page and also the classes .

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   BC30451 'btnAddnew' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

I have copied all the reference and all the scripts . Is there anything i could do .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried everything. There is no name spacing issues or anything the code behind is not recognizing the .aspx elements. I found two ways to resolve this:

1. You need to add a new form and copy the design and then go to code-behind and copy your code there. This solves the issue. But I won't suggest this for a larger project with number of classes this won't going to help .
2. This is the better solution so far to copy a project into new solution . Create a new project with empty forms. Now close the project and go to the source project file directory and copy all the files and folders and then paste it in the new project location. and then open the solution everything works.

Answer (score 0):

Probably has to do with the naming scope... check the first line of the web pages and make sure they reflect the new project identity.